# How to convert string to HTML safe string

Tags: c#, html, string, encoding

I am creating a some dynamically generated HTML

```
bldr.AppendLine("<a>");
string userText = user.Company;
bldr.AppendLine(userText);
bldr.AppendLine("</a>");
```

How can I ensure that whatever the company's name is, will appear as it should, but also if they try to inject any HTML in thier name it will simply appear in plain text.

For instance if they tried to use the name "`<script>alert("Do Bad!")</script>`" that's exactly what will appear on the page, in plain text.

But I also want to avoid "A & C" translating to "A \u0026 C", which is what happens when I use

```
HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(user.Company);
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use the same class `HttpUtility` you have use to javascript, but, for `html`, for sample:

```
bldr.AppendFormat("<a>{0}</a>\n", HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(user.Company));
```

There is also the inverse way using `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(string)`.

Answer (score 14):

An alternative without a dependency to System.Web:

```
System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode()
```

Comment: This encodes characters as HTML entities, e.g. "&" becomes "&amp;"

Answer (score 9):

```
using System.Web;

var encoded = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(unencoded);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`HttpUtility.HtmlEncode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73z22y6h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
var htmlString = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(user.Company);
```

Answer (score 1):

[`HtmlUtility.HtmlEncode(string s)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73z22y6h.aspx)

Comment: It's a method called `HtmlEncode` in the `HtmlUtility` class which takes a string parameter and encodes it into a Html-safe string. That's a 23-word description which doesn't add any information to my answer, which is why I didn't include it in the first place