# An recommendations on displaying HTML without WebView

Tags: webview, uwp, winrt-xaml, uwp-xaml

The `WebView` control cannot be transparent. In addition, it sizes in ways that don't enable simple XAML development, but complex sniffing and resizing.

I have a block of HTML that needs to be displayed in a simple, nice way. Is there any way to do this without `WebView` and parsing it all by hand?

Comment: The short answer is no. you cannot do that. You have to write your own parser as I did couple of months ago. You can use RichTextBlock to somewhat convert your HTML to XAML. I can share you my solution if you want.

Comment: WebView is the only built-in control capable of displaying arbitrary HTML.

Comment: Like this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23783679/how-to-convert-string-to-html-safe-string