# get all nodes and its content using htmldocument/HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, html, uwp, html-agility-pack

I need to get all nodes from a html, then from that nodes I need to get the text and sub-nodes, and the same thing but from that sub-sub-nodes.
For example, I have this HTML:

```
<p>This <b>is a <a href="">Link</a></b> with <b>bold</b></p>
```

So I need a way to get the **p** node, then the non-formatted text (this), the only-bold text (**is a**), the bolded link (**[Link](http://www.google.com/)**) and the rest formatted and not formatted text.

I know that with the htmldocument I can select all nodes and sub-nodes, but, how Can I get the text before the sub-node, then the sub-node, and its text/sub-nodes so I can make the rendered version of the html ("This **is a [Link](http://www.google.com/)** with **bold**")?

Please note that the above example is a simple one. The HTML would have more complex things like list, frames, numbered list, triple-formatted text, etc. Also note that the rendered thing is not a problem. I have already done that but in another way. What I need is the part to get the nodes and its content only.
Also, I can't ignore any node, so I can't filter by nothing. And the main node could start as p, div, frame, ul, etc.

Comment: Did you look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40183377/an-recommendations-on-displaying-html-without-webview)?

Comment: If you talk about Hasan's commentary, yes, I tried a repository that converts a HTML to XAML, but sadly my app is not that basic. For example, if there is a div with X class, I need to show an image, or if there is a <a> with an specific domain in the href, I need to call some function on click.

Comment: As mentioned in comment, There is no out of the box solution. You need to build your own parser that does all the stuff based on HTML Tags Manually one by one. Another thing that comes close to your requirement is [ScrollableHTMLView](https://github.com/MyToolkit/MyToolkit/wiki/ScrollableHtmlView)

Comment: I know that there is not any simple way like "htmldoc.toxaml();", but what I asking for is something like a list of nodes but including the not-formatted part. What i mean: you can get the main/root nodes and its childs, and from that childs you can get its childs and go on. But, if I'm correct, that childs are only formatted nodes (bold, a, ul, etc.). Again, i'm not asking for a 2 lines solution, but for a best way to improve my actual (2300 lines but with a lot of error of interpretation) code using htmldocument/htmlagilitypack

Comment: You can get the text before any nodes by looking for "#text" node. In your example it will be `<p><#text><b><#text><a><#text>` something like that. Let me know if you still couldnt figure out

Comment: @HungCao Thanks you, I was looking in the wrong way. Now that I inspected the HtmlDocument with more time I found a way to get all nodes, its type and its childs just like I need to. Soon I will add an answer to my question to help anyone with the same issue in the future.

Comment: @SunteenWu-MSFT Thanks. I have already tried with a Webview (in fact, the HTML is being extracted from a wordpress page), but the render was not so good, also I couldn't manipulate in a easy way the content and the actions. About the Example. I'll update my question to explain better the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking in the htmldoc and its properties, and thanks to @HungCao 's observation, I got a working simple way to interpretate a HTML code.

My code is a little more complex to add it as example, so I will post a lite version of it.

First of all, the htmlDoc has to be loaded. It could be on any function:

```
HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
string html = @"<p>This <b>is a <a href="""">Link</a></b> with <b>bold</b></p>";
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html);
```

Then we need to interpretate each "main" node (p in this case) and, depending its type, we need to load a LoopFunction (InterNode)

```
HtmlNodeCollection nodes = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.ChildNodes;

foreach (HtmlNode node in nodes)
{
    if(node.Name.ToLower() == "p") //Low the typeName just in case
    {
        Paragraph newPPara = new Paragraph();
        foreach(HtmlNode childNode in node.ChildNodes)
        {
            InterNode(childNode, ref newPPara);
        }
        richTextBlock.Blocks.Add(newPPara);
    }
}
```

Please note that there is a property called "NodeType", but it will not return the correct type. So, instead use the "Name" property (Also note that the Name property in htmlNode is not the same as the Name attribute in HTML).

Finally, we have the InterNode function that will add inlines to the referred (ref) Paragraph

```
public bool InterNode(HtmlNode htmlNode, ref Paragraph originalPar)
{
    string htmlNodeName = htmlNode.Name.ToLower();

    List<string> nodeAttList = new List<string>();
    HtmlNode parentNode = htmlNode.ParentNode;
    while (parentNode != null) {
        nodeAttList.Add(parentNode.Name);
        parentNode = parentNode.ParentNode;
    } //we need to get it multiple types, because it could be b(old) and i(talic) at the same time.

    Inline newRun = new Run();
    foreach (string noteAttStr in nodeAttList) //with this we can set all the attributes to the inline
    {
        switch (noteAttStr)
        {
            case ("b"):
            case ("strong"):
                {
                    newRun.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
                    break;
                }
            case ("i"):
            case ("em"):
                {
                    newRun.FontStyle = FontStyle.Italic;
                    break;
                }
        }
    }

    if(htmlNodeName == "#text") //the #text means that its a text node. Like <i><#text/></i>. Thanks @HungCao
    {
        ((Run)newRun).Text = htmlNode.InnerText;
    } else //if it is not a #text, don't load its innertext, as it's another node and it will always have a #text node as a child (if it has any text)
    {
        foreach (HtmlNode childNode in htmlNode.ChildNodes)
        {
            InterNode(childNode, ref originalPar);
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Note: I know that I said that my app need to render the HTML in another way that a webview does, and I know that this example code generate the same thing as a Webview, but, as I said before, this is just a lite version of my final code. In fact, my original/full code is working as I need to and this is just the base.